# Grammarly-like spellcheck dropdown on incorrect words in HTML textarea (Angular 8 Frontend)

Tags: html, angularjs, dom, textarea

The Chrome extension/plugin for Grammarly displays a dropdown of options whenever a word is spelled incorrectly (See image below for reference). How can I target a specific word in a textarea and target that area to add an html element, in this case the popup? I'm basically trying to recreate this functionality for an app. I am using Angular 8 on the frontend if that makes any difference.

[image: Grammarly_example]

Thank you for the help